# Adding multiple domain which have same DocumentRoot

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu

I added multiple domain on server and when i created separate directory for every domain then all works good. the problem is that we have to pint all the domain to same code. when does i make all domain DocumentRoot same then it redirect all do one domain.

Thanks
Vishwajeet

Answer (score 0):

Use the [ServerAlias](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#serveralias) directive.

Comment: ServerAlias  work for subdomains..i need for complete domain like on is www.xyz.com other www.xyz.net

Comment: I was thinking about downvoting your question because it doesn't seem like you cared to read any doc about this but now I am clearly doing it. Yes, it works for any name you want and you just earned a nice downvote.